# "present view controller" not working only on iOS 11.2

Tags: presentviewcontroller, ios11.2

This code works perfectly fine on anything before iOS 11.2:

```
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

The view is being presented from a **UITabBarController**

What is interesting is that **viewDidLoad** and **viewWillAppear** do get called for the **LoginView** but since it is never modally presented like on previous iOS versions **viewDidAppear** is never called.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you find any solution?